# Fastest way to match regex in R

Tags: r, regex, parsing

I need to parse in R around 1.6k REGEX expressions such as the pair I am writing below.

I have also around 7k documents (1/2 page long each in average) that need to be parsed according to the REGEX expressions.

Right now I am using

```
library(rebus)
library(stringr)

regex_exp <- rebus::or1("(?i-mx:\\b(?:actroid\\b))", "(?i-mx:\\b(?:robot\\*w\\b)))")

regex_exp <- BOUNDARY %R% regex_exp %R% BOUNDARY

stringr::str_extract_all("This is my text talking about technology, but also about the actroid", regex_exp)
```

to found matches, but it takes approx. 3.5 minutes per file, which is of course not scalable.

Is there a more efficient library/method to parse regex expression in R? I am also naive about whether using reticulate to parse in Python and go back to R could be faster.

According to [this site](https://rpubs.com/jonclayden/regex-performance), stringi (and therefore stringr which is the vectorised implementation) is much faster that base R.

Comment: do mean 1,600 reguler xpresunz ?

Comment: I've heard the same claims about `stringr` being faster in many cases. However, if you're having problems with *speed of execution*, you might need to consider something not in base R. Several options come to mind, with no attempted benchmarking: [`Rcpp` and regex](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/boost-regular-expressions/), python, julia, or perhaps `sed` if you have a well-defined collection of regexes.

Comment: it really a single rx `(?i)(?:\b(?:actroid|robot\*w)\b)` just comberne in wun, quohter `"(?i)(?:\\b(?:actroid|robot\\*w)\\b)"`

Comment: There is a way to do it quicker if you need to get matches from a regex like `\b(?:one_word|another_word|etc)\b` by building a regex trie. However, I see you have `actroid` as a whole word, but `robot` is only capped with a word boundary on the left. If it is so, you will just have to accept that speed if you invested time on preparing 1,600 regexps manually without first thinking of how to optimize these patterns.